# When to use null in java?

Tags: java, refactoring

Suppose I have a Node type.

```
public class Node{
  private Node next;
  private int data;

  // other methods including constructor and setting next reference.
}
```

Or using `null` for uninitialized value like below:

```
public class Node{
  private Node next = null;
  private int data;
}
```

Comment: Instance variables (aka fields) are already set to their _null value_ when creating an instance. So you already have `next = null` and `data = 0`. No need to set them explicitely.

Comment: In the first case, I'd use an Option Type. I'm fairly certain J8 has them.

Comment: The first is recommended. The second is redundant

Comment: In some case it might not be a bad idea to write the initial value even if it is the default value. For example when you want to highlight that some `boolean` value is `false` by default. There is no difference in the outcome though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Node{
  private Node next; //initialized to null
  private int data;  //initialized to 0

  // other methods including constructor and setting next reference.
}
```

Here `next` and `data` are instance variable and unlike local variables they are assigned default values. So `next` which is an Object will be assigned null value where as `data` which is an int will be initialized to 0.

So your each Node instance will have data initialized to 0 and next Node set to null. If you want some specific initializations you can do so in the constructor or use corresponding getter/setter methods.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between your examples, since uninitialized static and instance variables which are `Object` references are set to `null` by default.

If you want to model the case where `next` may or may point to another `Node` object you could use `Optional` ([docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)).

For example. You can initialize `next` pointing to `Optional.empty()`:

```
public class Node {
    private Optional<Node> next = Optional.empty();
    private int data;
}
```

Then later, when inserting the next node, you can do it like this:

```
void setNext(Node node) {
    this.next = Optional.of(node);
}
```

When accessing `next` you need to check if it is present or not.

```
if (next.isPresent()) {
    Node nextNode = next.get();
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

The advantage of using `Optional` in this case is that the fact that `next` may point to nothing is made explicit. Thus helping you avoid a possible `NullPointerException`.